# Swift: Data not fetching correctly from PHP

Tags: php, ios, swift

I am creating an app, where I am fetching the data from a php. To download the data from the php, I have a func  that downloads the data, submits to the model, and then retrieves it whenever needed. Now the issue is, when my data is fetched from the data base, it is not snyc appropriately and getting the same info every where. For example, Name shows the mob phone; street address also shows the same.

here is my code

```
    func download(){

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.some-site.com")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "id=\(businessID)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (request as URLRequest), completionHandler: { data, response, error in

            let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            let r = self.convertStringToDictionary(responseString!)

            for element in r! {

                print("element = \(element)")

                let stname = String(describing: element.first!)
                let sn = stname.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"STREET_NAME\", ", with: "")


                let name = String(describing: element.first!)
                let n = name.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"FILE_LOCATION\", ", with: "")

                let reverse = element.reversed()
                let fileloc = String(describing: reverse.first!)
                let f = fileloc.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"BUSINESS_NAME\", ", with: "")

                self.model = ProfilePage(fileloc: f, streetname: sn, name: n)

                print("Address = \(stname)")
                print("Name = \(name)")
                print("File Location = \(f)")

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.setUI()
                }
            }

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
            }

        })
        task.resume()
    }
}



but yes in my output console, i can see all the infor appropriate, its just when i run this, it shows all the info  as one
```

Screenshots
[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to describe your problem a bit better, maybe show some screenshots and a sample of what your server gives you back.

Comment: @Andy I have attached some screenshots. As you see in the output console, i am able to fetch the entire row but not in the simulator. It is taking all defaults values "Phone_Mobile"

Comment: @MohanSingh 9 , I didnt understand what you mean by post url and business ID

Comment: @MohanSingh, the ID is being passed from the previous view controller. It has the table inside a VC and the data is loaded from the database on each cell. when the cell is pressed, it navigates to another VC and fetches the data. The cell holds the businessId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me Know is this work for you,

```
let r = self.convertStringToDictionary(responseString!) // Make sure Your string is successfully converted as NSDictionary else use below
// let r = self.convertStringToDictionary(responseString!) as NSDictionary // if r is dictionary, then convert to NSDictionary
let stname = r["STREET_NAME"] as! String
let name = r["FILE_LOCATION"] as! String
let f = r["BUSINESS_NAME"] as! String
print("Address",stname)
print("Name",name)
print("File Location",f)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.setUI()
}
```

**If you confuse, then refer below example**

```
let mydict = ["Hip-Hop Tamizha": 21,"Hip-Hop Tamizha":"Takkaru Takkaru","Michael Jackson":"Beat It","Taylor Swift":"Back to December","Katy Perry":"Fire Works","Selina Gomez":"Love You Like A Love Song Baby","Avril Lavigne":"Slipped Away","Eminem":"The Music Box","Akhil":"Khaab","Hip-Hop Tamizha": 21,"Akhil": 61] as NSDictionary

let hop = mydict["Hip-Hop Tamizha"] as AnyObject
let swift = mydict["Taylor Swift"] as! String
print("The Number:",hop)
print("Taylor Swift song:",swift)
```

Comment: it works partially. I am getting the desired output in the output panel, but on the simulator its fetching all the same data. In my code i have the `for element in r!{print("element = \(element)") ....  }` it is picking  this value **element = ["PHONE_MOBILE": 0418288089** and displays this value everywhere.

Comment: And also having this error too:  Type '[String: AnyObject]?' has no subscript members

Comment: ` let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            let r = self.convertStringToDictionary(responseString!)
            
            for element in r! {
`

Comment: in my output panel: - i get this       Optional("[{\"id\":\"10300\",\"BUSINESS_NAME\":\"Miffy Excavation & Demolition P\\/L\",\"region\":\"North\",\"EMAIL\":\"\",\"WEBURL\":\"\",\"FACEBOOK_URL\":\"\",\"GOOGLEPLUS_URL\":\"\",\"TWITTER_URL\":\"\",\"YOUTUBE_URL\":\"\",\"NAME\":\"AIRPORT WEST\",\"ABOUT_US\":\"SPECIALISING IN ALL TYPES OF BOBCAT WORK[br]\\u000bBOBCAT - HOE & TIPPER[br]\\u000bOVER 20 YEARS EXPERIENCE[br][br]\\u000b\\u000bContact Tony Any Time![br][br]\\u0003\\u0003All Areas Covered\",\"PRODUCTS_SERVICES\":\"\",\"SPECIALS\":\"\",\"ADDITIONAL_LOCATION\":\"\",\"STREET_NO\":\"4\"]")

Comment: element = ["PHONE_MOBILE": 0407684139, "sunC": <null>, "sunO": <null>, "monC": <null>, "satC": <null>, "PRODUCTS_SERVICES": , "tueC": <null>, "id": 10300, "friC": <null>, "region": North, "thurC": <null>, "monO": <null>, "POSTCODE": 3042, "PHONE_FIXED": 93703513, "FACEBOOK_URL": , "tueO": <null>, "YOUTUBE_URL": , "wedC": <null>, "ADDITIONAL_LOCATION": , "STREET_NAME": Hart St, "wedO": <null>, "SPECIALS": , "BUSINESS_NAME": Miffy Excavation & Demolition P/L, "friO": <null>, "EMAIL": , "GOOGLEPLUS_URL": , "ABOUT_US": SPECIALISING IN ALL TYPES OF BOBCAT WORK[br]BOBCAT - HOE & TIPPER[br]OVER

Comment: `extension Profile_ViewController {

    func convertStringToDictionary(_ text: String) -> [[String:AnyObject]]? {
        if let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            do {
                return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]]
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
`

Comment: hope this help, sorry was bit lost :( trying to figure this out for last couple of days and being spending to many hours at work and outside

Comment: i am not too sure, but the element whats its retrieving is "PHONE_MOBILE": 04...] for all the records. its not mapping it appropriately from the database

Comment: so how can i correct this... can you please suggest. Thx

Comment: thanks @MohanSingh. but i was just wondering what does it show up on the sim? i am able to see the output in console with my current state of the code.

Comment: will you be able to share your email address, so that i can send you my code and you can help me to find where the error code is? if it suits you mate, thanks